# Java Generic Method Question

Tags: java, generics

Consider this code:

```
public <T> List<T> meth(List<?> type)
{
   System.out.println(type); // 1
   return new ArrayList<String>(); // 2
}
```

It does not compile at line 2, saying that List is required.

Now, if it's changed to:

```
public <T> List<?> meth(List<T> type)
{
   System.out.println(type); // 1
   return new ArrayList<String>(); // 2
}
```

It does compile. Why? I thought the difference between declaring a generic type with T and using the  wildcard was that, when using the wildcard, one cannot add new elements to a collection. Why would `<?>` allow a subtype of List to be returned? I'm missing something here, what's the explicit rule and how it's being applied?

Comment: What is your original goal? What do you want to accomplish with your method?

Comment: Nothing really, this isn't part of a project, I just wanna understand java generic methods. I' reading this right now http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the return type declaration.  `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<T>`, but it is a subtype of `List<?>`.

`List<?>` makes no assumptions regarding its type variable, so the following statements are valid:

```
List<?> l0 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> l1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<? extends Number> ltemp = null;
List<?> l2 = ltemp;
```

`List<T>` assumes that the type argument will be resolved in the context of client (e.g. type use), when you declared it as `List<String>` or `List<Object>`.  Within the method body, you cannot make any assumptions about it either.

Comment: I don't think the last compiles.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `T` is not necessarily a superclass of `String`. If you choose a `T` like `Integer` and call the method, it'll fail; so it won't compile. However, the second will compile as surely, any `ArrayList<String>` is a valid `List` of *something*.

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier, String isn't a subtype of T, so it's why it does not work. However, this code works :

```
public <T> List<T> meth(List<?> type)
{
   System.out.println(type); // 1
   return new ArrayList<T>(); // 2
}
```

and is more in the idea of what you want, I think.