# What does <?> mean in Android method signature?

Tags: java, generics

I 'm going through a code and found the following method declaration.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

What does `<?>` mean here?

Thank you.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "generics". I have updated the tags appropriately. See the related posts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844770/what-does-list-mean-in-java-generics , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777936/what-does-map-mean-in-java , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149964/java-generic-method-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AdapterView` is a *generic class*. It takes another data type as a parameter, and its operation is then customized towards that type, in a way. Normally, you'll declare an `AdapterView` something like

```
AdapterView<String> avs = new AdapterView<String>(...);
```

This refers to an `AdapterView` customized for `String`s.

Now, given all that: the `<?>` means that this method will accept an `AdapterView` regardless of the class it's customized for. It's a *wildcard* type specifier.